# WordPress Menu Link Issue

Tags: html, wordpress, parallax

I am currently developing a WordPress website.

I have home page as parallax page. you can visit [here](http://flykitely.cloudester.com). and parallax working fine on this page,

I have another page on same site which you can see [here](http://flykitely.cloudester.com/?page_id=330), you can also navigate to that page by clicking news menu link on home page.

My issue is, after navigating to news page,  other links ( Home, Services )  not working.

When I right click and choose **open link with new Tab** its working, but when i direct click that menu link (Home, Services ), Its not working, Why? What is missing there?

I have tried to bind jQuery click event with it, and click event in jQuery working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The browser is confused because you are using hashtags `#` in your url. Hashtags are normally used for links on the same page (anchors). The link is however not on the same page.

When you right-click and select `open in new tab` you are forcing the browser to go to a new page.

I do not know why the hastag is there in the first place. I suggest you remove it in the url. Do not forget the remove the hashtag in the slug of the page too.

Comment: It's because every other "page" is actually part of the home page. The menu is just directing to the anchors on the home page.

Comment: The hashtags are used on the homepage for the slide effect.

Comment: I see that now, but you are not on the homepage when you are on the 'news' page. So the browser is confused

Comment: This happens because your current page is loaded by the use of a query string parameter (?page_id=330) so the browser tries to find the anchor link with the hashtag in the same page (which it isn't.) If you switch to pretty permalinks, everything should be okay.

Comment: @AgeDeo  But I also need that when user click Services menu ( when user on news page), It should be redirected to home page annd Page scrolled up to services.

Comment: @E.Serrano I had tried to change the permalinks to the %postname%. But it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to test it with the pretty permalink structure (/news/) but I'm getting a _different_ IIS error when trying to view that. In theory, pretty permalinks should remove the anchor link ambiguity that @AgeDeO discovered, so the links with anchors should work there.

Answer (score 0):

your theme has an event on links with w-nav-anchor class in your js/plugins.js

Add more specific selector like '.home .w-nav-anchor' to run properly.